# why cant I download rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

this is the error I get :
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory.

I made sure I have ruby - 2.6 version
also nodes, yarn, home-brew, and sqlite3

cant figure out what I'm doing wrong tried both
sudo gem install rails
and gem install rails
I'm using a new Mac book pro

Comment: Nooooooooooo! Nooooooo! Noooo! Throwing `sudo` at any random command that fails is *not* the answer. This is *Apple's* Ruby installation. It is *only for internal use by Apple*. Do *not* change its permissions. Do *not* use `sudo`. Simply *do not use it at all*.

Comment: so how do I download rails then?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of different Ruby version managers that can be used to install Ruby on macOS like

- [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv)
- [RVM](https://rvm.io/)
- [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby)
- [asdf](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf)

You might want to read their documentation to understand the differences between them and to choose the manager that fits your needs best. The topic is quite opinionated.

Using a version manage has the advantage that you do not depend on the Ruby version installed and used by macOS internally that is on the one hand a bit outdated and on the other hand might change in the future. And it allows you to install multiple different versions at the same time on your machine which is handy when you work on different projects which require different versions or when you are upgrading your apps to a new version in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [RVM](https://rvm.io/) to install ruby then (without sudo): `gem install rails`

Comment: what does `ruby -v` outputs? it should not output `2.6`. If the error has a path, and you may need to `rm -r ~/.rvm` and reinstall rvm but without using sudo